# In PHP, for the code "$a='a';$b=$a;" allocates 2 units of memory or one unit?

Tags: php, memory

Because $a='a' allocates one byte but $b is not modified.

In PHP, for the code "$a='a';$b=$a;" allocates 2 units of memory or 1 unit?
how can I test it?

I can say that pseudoly like

```
alphahandler = new stringObj
alphahandler->insertContent('a');
variable a = alphahandler.objectHandler();
```

comes to b

```
variable b = a.getCurrentObjectHandler()
```

or just like

```
b=a.getCurrentObject().toContent()
```

??

Comment: You really shouldn't be worrying about this. Even in languages where you should care about memory use the use of a single variable with a scalar value is never going to be a source of significant memory.

Comment: As a practical matter, `$a = 'a'` would definitely allocate more than one byte. PHP is not C.

Comment: Also more like 400 bytes. The actual memory overhead comes from entries in the hash of the local variable scope.

Comment: um... I actually want to mean the comparison. I have changed the question due to that, thanks. I am not worrying about taking much memory or not but I want the concept for further development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How many times is memory allocated?

```
$a='a';   # creates a new string value, and assigns it to $a
$b=$a;    # assigns the SAME string value -- the one now in $a -- to $b
```

Ignoring that both variables also take up memory (and require separate variable entries), there is only *one* string object created from the above code.

That is, both *variables* now refer to the *same value*: there was no "copy" of the string created upon assignment.

#### How much memory is allocated?

There is *much more* memory being allocated (than say, 1 or 2 bytes): there is the memory *for the object* and then there is the memory *for each variable*.

While [this question relates to integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972170/what-is-the-overhead-of-using-php-int), similar stuff happens for strings (actually, more happens). A simple integer takes *at least* 72 bytes of memory. As mario suggested in a comment, this example may require upwards of 400 bytes.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding testing, you can use [`memory_get_usage();`](http://php.net/memory_get_usage) for an approximation.

See also:

- [memory_get_usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409477/memory-get-usage)
- [Tools to visually analyze memory usage of a PHP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255941/tools-to-visually-analyze-memory-usage-of-a-php-app)
- [Tracking Memory Usage in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290611/tracking-memory-usage-in-php)

Comment: Not really, because if he is testing such small quantities, then as soon as he uses `memory_get_usage`, he uses more memory than the quantity being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is a [link to another answer on so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7993775/608781), but I think it'll prove useful as this is a complicated matter.  what seems logical due to the way php *works* may not actually be how the core implementation will manage the memory.

[edit]
A simple script to illustrate the internals.

Strings are not objects in PHP - objects act totally differently than scalar variables.
If you're asking about string variables types the following script should shed some light on the internals.

```
<?php

header( 'content-type: text/plain' );
$a = 'a';
$b = $a;

echo '$b: ';  debug_zval_dump( $b );
$b = 'b';
echo '$a: '; debug_zval_dump( $a );
echo '$a: '; debug_zval_dump( $b );
```

**Output**

```
$b: string(1) "a" refcount(3)
$a: string(1) "a" refcount(2)
$a: string(1) "b" refcount(2)
```

[edit] - another illustration with memory usage

```
<?php

header( 'content-type: text/plain' );
$start = memory_get_usage();
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();
$a = 'a';
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();
$b = $a;
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();


echo '$b: ';  debug_zval_dump( $b );
$b = 'b';
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();
echo '$a: '; debug_zval_dump( $a );
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();
echo '$a: '; debug_zval_dump( $b );
echo 'Mem: ' . ( memory_get_usage() - $start ) . PHP_EOL; $start = memory_get_usage();
```

**Output**

```
Mem: 76
Mem: 88
Mem: 48
$b: string(1) "a" refcount(3)
Mem: 40
$a: string(1) "a" refcount(2)
Mem: 0
$a: string(1) "b" refcount(2)
Mem: 0
```

Comment: The refcount is higher than you'd expect because calling debug_zval_dump creates a copy of the var.